# Android studio creating HTML tags in XML autocomplete

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 3.4 over Win 10 pro, and have hit a weird effect on the autocomplete in the strings XML file. Here is an example, where I'm about to enter the string "a bird in the hand":

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Something</string>
  <string name="sname"></string>
</resources>
```

So when I add the string I get this:

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">Something</string>
  <string name="sname"><a><bird><in><the><hand></hand></the></in></bird> 
    </a></string>
</resources>
```

Each time I hit the space, the editor promptly converts it to an opening and closing tag. These tags are added to the breadcrumbs at the bottom of the editor, and I still have the warning "XML tag has empty body" - which is true. I seem to be unable to stop it doing this.

I'm learning this system, and it was working fine yesterday, so presumably it's something I've done. What I've tried so far to fix it is:

1. gone through every editor setting I can find. Nowhere can I see anything that implies that it will turn all input into tags.
2. created a new project - still happens.
3. Opened yesterday's project - where it worked - but the new behaviour is now fully in effect.
4. tried invalidating caches and restarting.
5. completely deleted the caches in the /System directory.

So I'm now stuck - any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: No idea. Maybe you installed a new plugin?

Comment: Not to my knowledge - I just installed Android Studio along with the SDKs as according to the recommendations. I'm new to Android programming.

Comment: maybe a bug in this release

Answer (score 0):

just replace this in your string

```
<string name="sname">a bird in the hand</string>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I understand. Are you suggesting using cut/paste? The simplest work-round is I'm using another editor: but I only need to do this for the strings file.